# Non-Transparent Msg Forwarding in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I am trying to use Gmail as a group messaging system between 3 people - A, B and C. I created a Gmail ID - D for this purpose. I then set rules in Gmail which work as follows -

1. If A sends an email to D, it is forwarded to B and C.
2. If B sends an email to D, it is forwarded to A and C.
3. If C sends an email to D, it is forwarded to A and B.

This does work, but the mail arrives as coming from A (B and C) instead of D. So if someone hits reply or reply all, it only goes to the original sender and not all. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not just use a Google Group? I have a group for just such a purpose: to facilitate email among four friends.

Comment: I really agree with @AlEverett (IMO, this would probably be the best answer btw). In your case, you would need to change the reply-to but I couldn't find any way to do this on the Google Help

Comment: What do you mean with forwarding? Normally the ones not receiving nor sending should be in CC. When hitting Reply All from there, the mail would go to the sender and the CC's would just be copied.

Answer (score 2):

Create a private Google Group for just those three people.

Or, use some other mailing list software/site. A mailing list doesn't have to have hundreds of people on it.